# how to pipe the output of cut to the foreach command?

Tags: linux, grep, scripting, pipe, cut

I have the cut command I want that grabs the first word in each line of a file.
I then want to put each word from the cut command into a foreach.
I then want to do a grep command inside the body of the foreach to grep for that word in another file.

Something like this:

```
@array = (cut /tmp/10218.after -f1); 
foreach $word (@lines) { 
   grep $word /tmp/10218.before;
}
```

Obviously the @array assignment doesn't work. How do I get around this?

I'm sure there are many ways I just don't know what they are or which is best or good enough.

Comment: ... what language? This looks like a mashup of bash, perl, and php?

Comment: bash. i'm more comfortable with perl than bash so my psuedocode may look more like perl than bash.

Comment: bash starts to fall apart nastily when trying to do arrays at all. Just pretend you can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash

```
while read -r word
do
    grep -q "$word" file.before
    if [ $? -ne "0" ]
    then
        echo "$word not in file"
     fi
done < <(cut -f1 -d" " file.after)
```

The `-q` to grep tells it to be quiet, you can then interrogate `$?` to see if there was a match `0` or not `1`.

Comment: beautiful. plus 1.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to do something more like this:

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/10218.after)
do
    grep $(echo ${i} | cut -f1) /tmp/10218.before
done
```

If you want to get a bit more fancy and output something if the grep fails you cand do something like:

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/10218.after)
do
    COUNT=grep -c $(echo ${i} | cut -f1) /tmp/10218.before
    if [[ ${COUNT} -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "${i}: Not Found"
    else
        echo "${i}: Found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: this is correct. Can I trouble you to tell me how to negate the grep. i.e. print a message (or something) when the grep fails. IOW I want to know if any of the words are NOT in the .before file.

Comment: redirect the grep to /dev/null, and then test $?.

Comment: You could have it `echo -n "$i: "` before the grep, and that would show you visually whether anything you're looping through from .after is missing in .before.

Comment: like this, @Sobrique: `grep $(echo ${i} | cut -f1) /tmp/10218.before > /dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: @Basil, I think that would get too busy and easy to miss in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %words_to_find;

open ( my $input, "<", "/tmp/10218.after" );
while ( my $line = <$input> )
{
  my ( $word ) = ( $line =~ m/\A(\S+)\s/ );
  $words_to_find{$word}++;
}
close ( $input );

open ( my $search, "<", "/tmp/10218.before" ); 
while ( my $line = <$search> )
{
  foreach my $word ( key %words_to_find )
  { 
    if ( $line =~ m/$word/ )
    {
      print $line;
      last;
    }
  }
}
close ( $search );
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Comment: a lot of "something like this"'s in this thread!

Answer (score 0):

What your code seems to be doing is to extract the first field in a tab-delimited list in one file, and then attempting to find those words in a second file.

You can simplify this somewhat by not storing the list of words in an array:

```
cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | grep -f /dev/stdin /tmp/10218.before
```

This would extract the words form the first file, and then pass them directly to `grep` as patterns to be used in matching against the second file.

There's a few optimisations we can do here though. First of all, we can make sure that the list of words only contain *unique* words:

```
cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | sort -u | grep -f /dev/stdin /tmp/10218.before
```

Secondly, we can make sure that `grep` does *string comparisons* instead of regular expression matches:

```
cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | sort -u | grep -F -f /dev/stdin /tmp/10218.before
```

And then, we possibly don't want `grep` to return matches for substrings (such as `bee` in `bumblebee`):

```
cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | sort -u | grep -wF -f /dev/stdin /tmp/10218.before
```

We could also make sure that we only match the words in the *first* column of the second file by rewriting the words as anchored regular expressions (and drop `-F`):

```
cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | sort -u | sed 's/^/^/' | grep -w -f /dev/stdin /tmp/10218.before
```

The `sed` command simply inserts `^` at the start of each line, so that instead of the string `bee` we get the regular expression `^bee`.

---

Or, we could just employ a single `awk` program to do everything for us:

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR == NR { words[$1]++; next } words[$1]' /tmp/10218.after /tmp/10218.before
```

This reads the first tab-delimited column of the first file into the array `words` as keys, and then checks the the words in the second file against these keys.  If a word in the second file occurs as a key, the line form the second file is printed.

---

If you don't care about the ordering of the output, you could also use `join`:

```
join <( cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | sort -u -b ) <( sort -b /tmp/10218.before )
```

This particular way of writing the command requires a shell (such as `bash`) that knows about process substitutions with `<(...)`.

In other shells:

```
cut -f1 /tmp/10218.after | sort -u -b -o keys
sort -b -o data /tmp/10218.before
join keys data
```